# Setup Failed: Visual Studio 2010 Pro installation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, installation

Trying to install VS2010Pro on Windows 7 (64bit) and i also checked all system requirements for the same.

**ERROR:**

[image]

**VIEW ERROR LOG:**

```
[05/15/12,10:48:22] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 64bit Prerequisites (x64): [2] Error: Installation failed for component Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 64bit Prerequisites (x64). MSI returned error code 1603
[05/15/12,10:48:22] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 64bit Prerequisites (x64) is not installed.
[05/15/12,10:48:22] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual F# 2.0 Runtime was not attempted to be installed.
[05/15/12,10:48:22] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates TFS Object Model (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[05/15/12,10:48:22] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack was not attempted to be installed.
[05/15/12,10:48:22] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[05/15/12,10:48:22] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Web Deployment Tool (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[05/15/12,10:48:22] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 - Visual Studio 2010 Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[05/15/12,10:48:22] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 was not attempted to be installed.
[05/15/12,10:48:22] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Silverlight 3 SDK was not attempted to be installed.
[05/15/12,10:48:22] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[05/15/12,10:48:22] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Office Developer Tools (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[05/15/12,10:48:22] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Dotfuscator Software Services - Community Edition was not attempted to be installed.
[05/15/12,10:48:22] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Crystal Reports templates for Visual Studio 2010 was not attempted to be installed.
[05/15/12,10:48:22] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 (x64) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[05/15/12,10:48:22] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Visual Studio 2010 Tools for SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[05/15/12,10:48:22] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime v1.0 (x64) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[05/15/12,10:48:22] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Services for ADO.NET v2.0 (x64) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[05/15/12,10:48:22] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework Services v1.0 (x64) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[05/15/12,10:48:22] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework SDK v1.0 (x64) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[05/15/12,10:48:22] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates VC 10.0 Designtime (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[05/15/12,10:48:22] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Publishing Wizard 1.4 was not attempted to be installed.
[05/15/12,10:48:22] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types was not attempted to be installed.
[05/15/12,10:48:22] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Objects was not attempted to be installed.
[05/15/12,10:48:22] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Objects (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[05/15/12,10:48:22] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express Service Pack 1 (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[05/15/12,10:48:22] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application Framework was not attempted to be installed.
[05/15/12,10:48:22] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application Project was not attempted to be installed.
```

**REF LINKS**
1. [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/c1f520fd-1966-4927-a7b3-7100747b19aa/)
2. [BLOG](http://ishaalan.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/error-installation-failed-for-component-microsoft-visual-studio-2010-64bit-prerequisites/) (tried)

have also asked question in [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssetup/thread/b3bbf748-acd6-40c7-93e1-1455bf13aaba) forum.

Do i have any better solutions to **trouble shoot this problem** other than re installing the OS ?

Comment: Please rate my answer if it has helped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After 2days of work around, Solution is finally here.....Phew!!!!!

Here we go,

As error indicated VS2010 was getting stuck while installing Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 64bit Prerequisites (x64)

```
Error: Installation failed for component Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 64bit Prerequisites (x64). MSI returned error code 1603
```

So i searched for the corresponding directory and ran .exe manually

```
VS2010Pro\adminpoint\WCU\64bitPrereq\x64
```

ran **VS_Prerequisites_x64_enu** & got one more **ERROR**

```
error 25541 failed to open xml file C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\machine.config, system error -2147024786
```

Looked for machine.config in indicated path, but I couldn't find **machine.config** in

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG
```

So i copied **machine.config.default on to desktop and renamed it to machine.config** and added it to  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG then ran VS_Prerequisites_x64_enu & then VS2010 installer.

```
VS_Prerequisites_x64_enu ---> (finally) VS2010 installer
```

**Note:** by doing this i tricked installer & installation went smooth.

More details [HERE](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssetup/thread/b3bbf748-acd6-40c7-93e1-1455bf13aaba)

Answer (score 2):

Error code 1603: solution can be found at this msdn link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/vssetup/thread/3f07772c-4187-4be7-a390-d775f8eb5a50

If its not solved please try to post it here in [VisualStudio Setup & Installation](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssetup/threads) forum. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue today and fixed it by reinstalling the .NET frameworks 4.5 and 4.0

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17851

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with the software you downloaded , its not downloaded completely, thats why that error , 
i also experienced the same , but i resolved it by redownloading the software,

after downloading check that the size of downloaded and the mentioned size in the website are same , if not its not downloaded completely, again download it and install

Answer (score 0):

You might have missing machine.config file.

Location: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem installing visual studio 2010 professional on a Windows 8.1 machine. 
I tried to install Visual Studio from a local directory, but this failed.
Although all the files from the DVD looked exact the same as on the local directory I recopied all the files again and this time I had success with installing.

I also followed these steps found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2011/12/13/10141564.aspx) to install without typing in the Product Key and your custom settings. And adding SP1 with the installation as well. 
It didn't solved the problem, but I installed the software with unattended setup.

Answer (score -1):

I had a corrupted image that I downloaded and got the same result. My advice is to run the installer of a component individually; corrupted setups should fail immediately.