# assembly alias reference dependency object exception

Tags: c#, .net

I have a project that has the "System.dll" and "System.Windows.dll" and both are needed.

You will see in the code below when trying to reference my aliased assembly (right clicked on the assembly in the project -> went to properties and changed the alias from global to MediaLibrary) I get the follower error.

I appreciate your help and guidance.

```
 #region Usings

 using System;
 using System.IO;
 extern alias MediaLibrary;
 using Media = MediaLibrary.System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

#endregion Usings

#region Public methods

public void foo()
{
...
// ERROR HERE : TypeInitializationException occured. The type initializer
//              for 'System.Windows.DependencyObject' threw an exception.
Media.BitmapImage image = new Media.BitmapImage(); 
image.SetSource(new MemoryStream(byteBuffer));
...
}

#endregion Public methods
```

Comment: Can you share more of the exception? Specifically the InnerException and / or stack trace.

Comment: Please send inner exception, I think you need more dependent library.

Comment: INNER EXCEPTION:
"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Xml, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: Which version of .Net was the MediaLibrary.System.Windows.Media.Imaging built against, and which version is your app using? Are you mixing up the PCL / regular framework? Are you referencing System.Xml in your project? If so, which version?

Comment: @Allan Elder : Looks like the DLL i was referencing was for .NET v2.0.5.0 but my project is being build with .NET v4.0.0.0. I cannot find a v4 System.Windows.dll anywhere, but i can find a v4.5 of System.Windows.dll. Was this DLL not included in .NET v4.0.0.0?

Comment: Yes, it was; but 4.5 overwrites 4.0 in the GAC. When you build with 4.0 in VS2012, it actually uses a copy of the 4.0 framework it keeps in the VS directories, but 4.5 is in the GAC. Big mistake on MS's part IMHO.

Comment: @AllanElder Can you elaborate I'm not sure I understand your acronyms. What is GAC? And are you saying if I import the v4.5 System.Windows.DLL it will work?

Comment: GAC = Global Assembly Cache - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz(v=vs.110).aspx - When MS went from .Net 2.0 to 4.0 they were installed in separate dirs so both versions can exist on the machine (a side by side upgrade). When they released 4.5, it overwrote 4.0 in the GAC (an in place upgrade) which led to some compatibility issues. My point was you should still be able to reference the 4.0 DLL on your machine as VS definitely installs it somewhere.

Comment: Actually; I take that back, there are some extra steps to use 4.0 with 2012 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567193/multi-targeting-net-framework-4-and-visual-studio-2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to my comments above, the supportedRuntime property in your app.Config should allow you to support earlier versions of the framework

```
    <configuration>
       <startup>
           <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
       </startup>
    </configuration>
```

see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/w4atty68%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more info

Based on your new comments above, I would try targeting 4.5 in VS2012 and then bringing in 2.0.5 as a supportedRuntime version through the app.Config