# setup Failed : Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate

Tags: visual-studio

setup Failed : Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate

Iam Try to install Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate show me the error that demonstrate the figure please tell me how solve it step by step.

Comment: excuse me my photo does not uploaded correctly  but figure same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605224/setup-failed-visual-studio-2010-pro-installation . show in the link

Comment: If the error message is exactly the same as in the linked post did you try the proposed solution?